# Property set accessor in controller not being executed by apex:selectList value attribute

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, class, selectlist

I have a Visualforce form with the following pageBlockSection:

```
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Vehicle">
            <apex:selectList id="manufacturer" label="Manufacturer" value="{!selectedManufacturer}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!manufacturers}"/>
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="model"/>
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:selectList id="model" label="Model" size="1">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!models}"/>
            </apex:selectList>                
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Code in the controller extension looks like this.

```
Public String selectedManufacturer {
    get {
        System.debug('Getting selectedManufacturer property value!');
        return selectedManufacturer;
    }
    set {
        // THIS BLOCK IS NOT GETTING EXECUTED!!!!
        System.debug('**Setting** selectedManufacturer property value!');
        selectedManufacturer = value;
    }
}

// Populate the manufacturer picklist.
public List<SelectOption> getManufacturers() {
    List<SelectOption> manufOptions;
    manufOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    System.debug('Hit the getManufacturers code!');
    manufOptions.add(new SelectOption('BMW', 'BMW'));
    manufOptions.add(new SelectOption('Jaguar', 'Jaguar'));
    manufOptions.add(new SelectOption('Mercedes', 'Mercedes'));
    return manufOptions;
}

// Populate the model picklist.
public List<SelectOption> getModels() {
    List<SelectOption> modelOptions;
    modelOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    System.debug('Hit the getModels code!');
    System.debug('selectedManufacturer set to: ' + selectedManufacturer);
    if(selectedManufacturer == 'BMW') {
        modelOptions.add(new SelectOption('3 Series', '3 Series'));
        modelOptions.add(new SelectOption('5 Series', '5 Series'));
        modelOptions.add(new SelectOption('7 Series', '7 Series'));
    }
    else if(selectedManufacturer == 'Jaguar') {
        modelOptions.add(new SelectOption('XF', 'XF'));
        modelOptions.add(new SelectOption('XK', 'XK'));
    }
    else if(selectedManufacturer == 'Mercedes') {
        modelOptions.add(new SelectOption('B-Class', 'B-Class'));
        modelOptions.add(new SelectOption('C-Class', 'C-Class'));
        modelOptions.add(new SelectOption('E-Class', 'E-Class'));
    }
    else if(selectedManufacturer == null) {
        modelOptions.add(new SelectOption('AAARGH!', 'AAARGH!'));
    }
    return modelOptions;
}
```

I have debugged fairly extensively and the root of the problem seems to be the selectedManufacturer property set accessor is not being executed in the controller extension.

Can anybody see what the problem might be? I have been working on this for nine hours now, and I'm starting to go round in circles.

Comment: Is your selectList `manufacturers` getting populated?

Comment: @EricSSH Yes, that list is populated fine. The picklist shows BMW, Jaguar and Mercedes as expected.

Comment: I don't believe you need to do this `selectedManufacturer = value;` I think you might be emptying because value is `null`

Comment: @EricSSH I just tried commenting out that line and it hasn't made a difference. That property set accessor block still isn't being executed.

Comment: @Brian The posted code is just fine. I think somehow you are making selectedManufacturer null or set to something else outside of this code.

Comment: @SarojBera You may have saved my sanity. I have stripped out all other code from the class and all other elements from the Visualforce page and these two picklists now work perfectly. I will add things back in and report here when I find the cause. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this problem by stripping out all the other elements on the Visualforce page. It worked perfectly with only the picklists on the page, so I started adding back the other elements one-by-one, and retesting each time.

Everything worked fine until I came to add a mandatory field back to the Visualforce page, then the property set accessor immediately stopped working again. It seems this accessor is only getting fired once all mandatory fields on the form have entries in them.

This is pretty strange behaviour and less than ideal because it forces users to complete all mandatory fields before they can use these picklists, but at least the original problem is now solved.

I hope this answer saves somebody else several hours of pain!